# VB.NET Error in class is not thrown

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have the following code in a class:

```
Private WithEvents AH As ActiveHomeScriptLib.ActiveHome

Public Sub New()

    Try
        AH = New ActiveHomeScriptLib.ActiveHome
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteLog("#clsCM15Pro_Class_Initialize: " & Information.Err().Description & ", err.number: " & CStr(Information.Err().Number) & ", Params: '" & "" & "'")
    Finally

    End Try

End Sub
```

The line "WriteLog" is not reached.
I have set a breakpoint at "End Sub", but it is never reached.

I have the following exceptions activated:
[image]

Does anybody see any mistakes that I could have done here that would cause the behaviour that I experience?

Edit: I have created a new project now.
There is only 1 form, and a button on it.

A click on the button does the following:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim c As clsCM15Pro
    c = New clsCM15Pro

    MsgBox("Blah!")

End Sub
```

But the messagebox is not shown. Instead, my application just quits in the IDE after a click on the button.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why do you expect the call to `ActiveHomeScriptLib.ActiveHome` to fail?

Comment: Where are you instanciating this class?

Comment: All code after ActiveHomeScriptLib.ActiveHome is not executed, so I guess that is where something goes wrong.

Comment: I am instantiating this class in another class.

Comment: Is it in a Form Load event handler?

Comment: Well. I do have a startup form, and from there I instantiate classes. But what would be the difference to a different scenario?

Comment: If you set a break point on the `AH = ` line does it get hit?

Comment: @tmighty the reason I was asking is there is an issue with errors not being shown if they are thrown in a 64 bit compiled application in the form load event

Comment: @JaredPar Yes, AH = gets hit.

Comment: @MarkHall My application is 32bit.

Comment: ps: My code runs fine when I take out the AH =. I mean all subsequent code is then called.

Comment: @tmighty is it possible the code is throwing a stack overflow here?  That would fit the symtoms

Comment: @JaredPar How could I check this?

Comment: @Jared Par I am not sure what I changed in the project settings, I guess it was "Enable system debugger" or something like that. Now when I run my code, I get the error message "First change excpetion in application1.exe: Multiple float point traps." It would be cool if I could catch this error and avoid having my app go berzerk, but I don't know yet how to do this. I guess COM DLL errors are not so easy to catch in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a missing DLL that the AH referenced internally. When it did not find this DLL, this resulted in an unexpected behaviour: No error was thrown in VB.NET. 
The only way to work around this (without having the AH code... it is a third party DLL), was to first check if the DLL in question exists, and only if it does, go on. Else skip to ship around such strange behaviour.